# Delphi firemonkey HTTP Put body parameter

Tags: http, delphi, firemonkey, put

What is the correct way to write a stringstream using `TIdHTTP.Put()` in Delphi FireMonkey?

I have a PHP API (slim) like this:

```php
// Update user
$app->put('/api/user/update/{id}', function(Request $request, Response $response){
    $id = $request->getAttribute('id');
    $username = $request->getParam('username');
    $password = $request->getParam('password');
    $nama = $request->getParam('nama');
    $alamat = $request->getParam('alamat');
    $jenis_kelamin = $request->getParam('jenis_kelamin');
    $foto = $request->getParam('foto');

    $sql = "UPDATE user SET
        username    = :username,
        password    = :password,
                nama        = :nama,
                alamat      = :alamat,
                jenis_kelamin   = :jenis_kelamin,
                foto        = :foto
            WHERE id = $id";

    try{
        // Get DB Object
        $db = new db();
        // Connect
        $db = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password',  $password);
        $stmt->bindParam(':nama',      $nama);
        $stmt->bindParam(':alamat',      $alamat);
        $stmt->bindParam(':jenis_kelamin',    $jenis_kelamin);
        $stmt->bindParam(':foto',       $foto);

        $stmt->execute();

        echo '{"notice": {"text": "Customer Updated"}';

    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});
```

The procedure in Delphi for posting data via HTTP is like this:

```pascal
procedure TForm3.updateexample;
var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  lParamList: TStringList;
  stream : TStringStream;
  mydata,json: string;

begin


 json := 'username='+edtusername.Text+
          'password='+edtpassword.Text+
          'nama='+edtnama.Text+
          'alamat='+edtalamat.Text+
          'jenis_kelamin='+cbbjkel.Selected.Text+
          'foto="'+edtalamat.text;

  stream := TStringStream.Create(json,Tencoding.UTF8);

  //create
  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try

    mydata := lHTTP.put
      ('http://myweblablalbalbala/api/user/update/'+id,stream); 

    if Pos('Customer Updated', mydata) > 0 then
    begin
      ShowMessage('Update Succes');
    end
    else
      ShowMessage('update fail');
  finally
    lHTTP.Free;
    lParamList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The code works, but after sending an update, the data changes from this (before the update):

```json
{"id":"1","username":"iboy","password":"123456","nama":"ishak","alamat":"cikupa","jenis_kelamin":"l","foto":"iboy.jpg"}
```

to this (after the update):

```json
{"id":"1","username":"","password":"","nama":"","alamat":"","jenis_kelamin":"","foto":""}
```

Can you help me?  What is the correct way to post a stringstream via HTTP I Delphi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not formatting your `TStringstream` data correctly.  It is not even close to being JSON (despite your variable name).  And you are also not setting the `TIdHTTP.Request.ContentType` property so the server knows what kind of data you are actually sending.

If you read the [Slim documentation](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/request.html), Slim supports the following media types out of the box:

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- application/json
- application/xml & text/xml

The data you are trying to send is closest to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  That is normally sent using `TIdHTTP.Post()` instead of `TIdHTTP.Put()`, by giving it a `TStrings` object of `name=value` pairs.  `Post()` will format the values in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format for you, and set the `Request.ContentType` property to match.

Your `PHP` is expecting a `PUT` request instead of a `POST` request.  Per the Slim documentation, you can actually send a `POST` request and make it act like a `PUT` request, by either:

- including a `_METHOD=PUT` value in your data (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` only)
- including an `X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT` HTTP request header (works with any media type).

Try something more like this:

```
procedure TForm3.UpdateExample;
var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  lParamList: TStringList;
  lReply: string;
begin
  lParamList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    lParamList.Add('username='+edtusername.Text);
    lParamList.Add('password='+edtpassword.Text);
    lParamList.Add('nama='+edtnama.Text);
    lParamList.Add('alamat='+edtalamat.Text);
    lParamList.Add('jenis_kelamin='+cbbjkel.Selected.Text);
    lParamList.Add('foto='+edtalamat.Text);

    lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    try

      // use one of these, not both!
      lParamList.Add('_METHOD=PUT');
      lHTTP.Request.MethodOverride := 'PUT';

      lReply := lHTTP.Post('http://myweblablalbalbala/api/user/update/'+id, lParamList); 

      if Pos('Customer Updated', lReply) > 0 then
        ShowMessage('Update Success')
      else
        ShowMessage('Update Fail');
    finally
      lHTTP.Free;
    end;
  finally
    lParamList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another Way (without Indy), multiplatform, better than with Indy:

```
function Upload(const aFilePath: string): boolean;
var
  vData: TMultipartFormData; // uses System.Net.Mime
  vHTTP: THTTPClient; // uses System.Net.HttpClient
  vCRC: cardinal;
  vURL: string;
  vResp: TStringStream;
begin
  vURL := 'PHP url';
  vResp := TStringStream.Create('');
  vData := TMultipartFormData.Create();
  vHTTP := THTTPClient.Create;
  try
    try
      vData.AddField('version', MyVerField.ToString);
      vData.AddField('crc', MyCRC.ToString);

      vData.AddFile('db_file', aFilePath);
      Result := vHTTP.Post(vURL, vData, vResp).StatusCode = 200;

      if Result then 
        Result := vResp.DataString.ContentAsString().Contains('"result":true');          

    except
      Result := false;
    end;
  finally
    vHTTP.Free;
    vData.Free;
    vResp.Free; 
  end;
end;
```